# Change a resource by deletion of existing followed by insertion of new. Still a PUT?

Tags: rest

I'm working on a REST-like API. 
This API have a this for changing a existing resource by ID:

```
/api/v1/admin/member/:ID
```

I any normal circumstances this would of course be a `PUT` when changing a resource.

But because of a compromise leading to simpler code, this route actually first delete the resource completely (and all references to it) and then create a new one based on the input given by a form. 
In all means this will look and give the same end result as a resource *change*.

**Question**: Should this route be a `PUT` or a `POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected behavior is idempotent so I would say use `PUT`, and I would make sure the update occurs in a transaction so an error between deleting and inserting would not leave the resource deleted.